# Generate Random Number - Put into List - Print List

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a program that generates a list of numbers and computes all into a total and separates them into three different list. One being all of the numbers, and the other two are even and odd and then prints the even and odd array-list.

or some reason when I try to print out the two list, it only prints the first couple of numbers in the ArrayList giving my no error messages.

My Code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Projects {
public static void main(String [] args) {

Random Generate = new Random ();
ArrayList<Double> List = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Double> Even = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Double> Odd = new ArrayList<>();


double number;
double total = 0;
double totalEven = 0;
double totalOdd = 0;
double averageWhole;
double averageEven;
double averageOdd;

System.out.println("Generating Numbers:");    
for (int Repeater = 0; Repeater < 10; Repeater++) {
    number = Generate.nextInt(100);
    List.add(number);   
}
System.out.println("Loaded... " + "Putting Numbers Into List");
System.out.println();

for(int Insert = 0; Insert < 3; Insert++) {
    System.out.println("Adding To List...");
}
System.out.println("List Completed!");
System.out.println();
System.out.println();
for (int x = 0; x < List.size(); x++) {
    total += List.get(x);   
    //Complicated Code --- really big for loop try to simplify later. 
    if (List.get(x) % 2 == 0) {
        Even.add(List.get(x));  
    }
    else {
        Odd.add(List.get(x));
    }
}   
System.out.println("Your Total Is: " + total);
System.out.println();
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Even Numbers:" + "\t" + "Odd Numbers");

for (int Output = 0; Output < Even.size() && Output < Odd.size(); Output++)         
{
    System.out.println(Even.get(Output) + "\t" + "\t" + Odd.get(Output));
}
averageWhole = total / List.size();
System.out.println("Average of All Numbers:     " + "Average of All Even Numbers:     "+ "Average of all Odd Numbers:     "  );
for (int averageE = 0; averageE < Even.size(); averageE++) {
    totalEven = totalEven + Even.get(averageE);  
}
averageEven = totalEven / Even.size();

for (int averageO = 0; averageO < Odd.size(); averageO++) {
    totalOdd = totalOdd + Odd.get(averageO);  
}
averageOdd = totalOdd / Odd.size();

System.out.print(averageWhole + "\t" + "\t" + "\t" + "    " + averageEven + "\t" + "\t" + "\t" + "\t" + "     " + averageOdd);
System.out.println();
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Command Complete...");
```

Sorry for it being so compacted - learning java - 2/3 weeks in -- Thanks!

Comment: PLEASE indent code correctly for readability.

Answer (score 0):

When you are printing the odd and even numbers the condition in the loop will be met when the shorter list will be done, so the printing stops before printing all the numbers. You separate the printing to two separate loops.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Even.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(Even.get(i));  
}

for (int i = 0; i < Odd.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(Odd.get(i));  
}
```

As a side note, variables in Java should start with lowercase. `Even`, `Odd`, `Output` etc should be `even`, `odd`, `output`.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to Guy's code that keeps the same format:

```
for (int Output = 0; Output < Even.size() || Output < Odd.size(); Output++) {
String even = "-";
if(Output < Even.size()){
    even = Even.get(Output).toString();
}//end of if
String odd = "-";
if(Output < Odd.size()){
    odd = Odd.get(Output).toString();
}
System.out.println(even + "\t" + "\t" + odd);
}
```